# Consistuency vs Dependency Parsing with example

Tags: nlp

I would like to illustrate the difference between those two parser. Yet I am not sure if my representation is correct and would love to get some input:

[image]

Comment: seems correct to me

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most common way to draw either kind of parse (constituency parses usually don't use arrows and dependency parses usually don't use arrows to link words with POS tags), but the basic structures are okay. In the dependency parse `VDB` (I think you mean `VBD`) should be linked to `drove`.